# Преобразование строки в таблицу значений

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, unpivot

Есть такая строка:

```
X       vl  v2  v3  v4
------  --- --- --- ---
ffff    34  555 66  23
```

Как запросом можно получить из неё таблицу значений?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: известны ли изначально список колонок v1, v2, v3 ... или этот список - динамический?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Преобразование колонок в строки == UNPIVOT. Вот так:

```
with data (x, v1, v2, v3, v4) as (  
    select 'ffff', 34,  555, 66, 23 from dual   
)
select *
from data unpivot (col_value for col_name in (v1, v2, v3, v4)) 
/

X    COL_NAME  COL_VALUE
---- -------- ----------
ffff V1               34
ffff V2              555
ffff V3               66
ffff V4               23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (
      x varchar(20) ,
      v1 int ,
      v2 int ,
      v3 int ,
      v4 int
    );

INSERT  INTO test
VALUES  ( 'ffff', 34, 555, 66, 23 );

SELECT x,
       unnest(array['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4']) AS col_name,
       unnest(array[v1, v2, v3, v4]) AS col_value
FROM test
ORDER BY 2;
```

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/44ea5/3)

Comment: В pl/sql не работает